# 2D WASD only movement isnt working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to make a local coop top down 2D game in unity where you and another player play with WASD and the arrow keys. However, the code im using only works for two buttons, if i delete the code of one of the working buttons, then another one will work. This code is just for WASD, the arrow keys code will be identical to this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    Vector2 movement;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) == true) //move right
        {
            movement.x = 1;
        }
        else //stop move right
        {
            movement.x = 0;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) == true) //move left
        {
            movement.x = -1;
        }
        else //stop move left
        {
            movement.x = 0;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) == true) //move up
        {
            movement.y = 1;
        }
        else //stop move up
        {
            movement.y = 0;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) == true) //move down
        {
            movement.y = -1;
        }
        else //stop move down
        {
            movement.y = 0;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which buttons work, "A" and "S" by any chance? Comment out all `else` clauses to see what happens. The problem should be that you're always resetting `x` and `y` to `0` in the `else` clauses.

Comment: @ewerspej all keys now work, however when i let go of a key, the player will keep moving in the direction it was left moving in, that was why i was resetting the movement to 0 when i let go of the key. is there any other way to detect the key isnt being pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "D" and "W" keys cannot work, because the `else` clauses of "A" and "S" will overwrite the values for `movement.x` and `movement.y`.

To fix this, you should update the code in the `Update()` method like this:

```cs
void Update()
{
    var keyD = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);
    var keyA = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
    var keyW = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
    var keyS = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S);

    if(keyD || keyA)
    {
        if(keyD)
        {
            movement.x = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            movement.x = -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        movement.x = 0;
    }

    if(keyW || keyS)
    {
        if(keyW)
        {
            movement.y = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            movement.y = -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        movement.y = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for all the help man! everything is working now, gotta replicate it for arrows and it'll all be good!